# To ensure an action happens only once during a recursive call

Tags: python, recursion

I have a procedure which contains a step which involves calling the procedure recursively. I want a certain action to be not done the first time but done the other times it is called recursively.

```
def a(string):
    while string.startswith('/'):
        string =string[1:]
    stringa = string.split('/',1)

    if(len(stringa)>1):
        a(stringa)
```

Basically my string is of type `/a/b/c/d`. I want to have stringa as `{/}{a/b/c/d}` during the first time and the successive recursion as 
                    
stringa ={a}{b/c/d}
                    
stringa ={b}{c/d} 
                    
stringa ={c}{d}

Comment: think of having a flag initially set to false , but set to true once it exists the loop

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried debugging by printing stringa before the recursive call, and trying to get stringa to be in the format you want? Also print string at the start of a() would be a good idea. Recursive functions can be a total pain to debug, consider using a for loop instead if you can, also makes it easier to implemenmt your first-time only action because there isn't any recursion any more, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Your code does not work anyway, because you expect a string but `stringa` is a list.

Answer (score 7):

The basic pattern is to use a flag. You can set the flag as a default parameter so you don't have to pass it when first calling the function, then the function sets (or unsets...) the flag when calling recursively.

It looks something like this:

```
def some_function(..., is_first=True):
    if is_first:
        # code to run the first time
    else
        # code to run the other times
    # recurse
    some_function(..., is_first=False)
```

I don't know exactly how to translate that to your code because it's not clear what you want to do only on the first time. Plus, you start by passing in a string, but your recursive call is passing in a list.